# Why does my webpage appear different in Incognito mode?

Tags: css, browser, incognito-mode

I synchronized my project with a remote, but it looks different locally than when hosted online. Locally, it appears like this:

[image]

But looks like this online:

[image]

I refreshed the Chrome browser multiple times to no avail, but found that the styles showed up correctly in Incognito mode. Why?

Comment: Caching CSS files? In Incognito, caching is fresh.

Comment: Is it  a convention to test in incoginito mode? @Li357

Comment: Yes. It gives you a clean environment to see your apps without any cached content.

Comment: You could try pressing Ctrl+F5 for hard refresh if you are in non-incognito mode

Comment: ty, could you please transmit the comment to answer as a forward reference. @Li357

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely due to Chrome's caching of your files. Due to caching, you're seeing an old version of your styles. In incognito mode, this is not a problem because Chrome uses a fresh cache when you start a session and removes that cache when you end the session. You can solve your problem by clearing your cache.

In general, it's a good idea to test your application in incognito mode because it gives you a good idea what someone sees when they first visit a site, and it allows you to experience your application in a clean environment without any extensions or cache.

Answer (score 5):

Your internet browser stores "cached" versions of your website to improve load speed. Normally this isn't a problem, but it'll often interfere with showing the new styles whenever you're doing web development.

Try clearing your cache. There are some useful [Chrome browser plugins](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/clear%20cache?hl=en) you can use for this, or you can do it in the [Chrome settings](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).